# Generate a continous column from column with blanks using formulas only (no VBA)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column A:

```
1Q14
2Q14
3Q14
4Q14
''
''
''
''
h4
j4
k4
m4
```

and I want to have this in column B:

```
1Q14
2Q14
3Q14
4Q14
h4
j4
k4
m4
```

What am I supposed to put into column B to get it?

Comment: Tried putting '=INDEX(A15:$A$150,MATCH(TRUE,LEN(A15:$A$150)<>0,0),1)' -> which finds first non empty cell but the I get a series of duplicate h4's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `SMALL` is usually better than `MATCH` in those situations. For instance, try this:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$15:$A$150,SMALL(IF($A$15:$A$150<>"",ROW($A$15:$A$150)-ROW($A$15)+1),ROWS($A$15:A15))),"")
```

In row 15 of column B. Enter it as an array formula (i.e. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>)

Change the range accordingly.

Comment: @LucasSeveryn You're welcome! Um, I meant to add something else to my answer but forgot while typing down the formula ^^;. Would you be interested in another solution involving copy/paste and delete alone?

Comment: @LucasSeveryn Okay, that's fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this array formula (Ctrl + Shift + Enter to enter this formula)

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$12,SMALL(IF(LEN($A$1:$A$12)>0,ROW($A$1:$A$12),9999999999999),ROW())),"")
```

Comment: Change the range address as per your requirements and I assumed that ' ' means blank cells if they are not blank cells than let me know.