# How to search for data in excel with a function

Tags: excel, function, math, ms-office

I'm currently working on a school assignment which involves using Excel.

One of the tasks is to get the rows from a sheet, where the column "Browser" has the value "Internet explorer" or "Chrome"

Now of course, there are also other values there, like Firefox, or no value at all. Which function should I use to search for only Internet Explorer or Chrome and get those rows?

Regards

Comment: Do you know where the column 'Browser' is? Is the data in a Table (when I say Table, it is one which is specifically formatted in excel as a Table) or simply on the sheet? What should happen if both `Internet explorer` and `Chrome` is in the column but on different rows?

Comment: Yes, Browser is in the H column. We simply need to go over each row and find those who either have Internet explorer or Chrome and get all the data from that row.

Say that row 1 contains Chrome, then I need that row.
Row 2 contains firefox, skip that row.
Row 3 contains Chrome, I need that row

Comment: Hmm, it would be simpler if you use filters and [filter](http://i.stack.imgur.com/T5Y7X.png) on Column H, check on 'Chrome' and 'Internet Explorer'. That will hide all the other values. From there, you can copy the rows to where you need them. Otherwise, one function returns information in one cell, which means: if you want to get the whole row, you'll need to repeat the same function many times.

Comment: I don't think that's what my teacher expects us to to. We should use some sort of function or create a query of some sort to retrieve the wanted data from the spreadsheet

Comment: Are you supposed to be writing a VB script? If not, I can suggest this... [rather complex formula](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22530071/1578604) which works. You only need to change the ranges, and change the condition in the if from `$A$15:$A$150<>""` to `($H$2:$H$150="chrome")+($H$2:$H$150="internet explorer")` (with the appropriate rows) and use this formula to retrieve each column.